# Docker Namespace in kernel level

Tags: docker

How to differentiate pid 1,17 etc of docker containers with host's 1,17 etc pid's and what all the kernel changes are happening when we create a new process inside the docker container?

How the process inside the docker can be seen in the host?

Comment: "How the process inside the docker can be seen in the host?": that is what I was mentioning in my answer: `--pid host`

Comment: Host process can be seen in docker but process id's of docker container cant be seen in host..why is that so? How we can differentiate between both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to differentiate pid 1,17 etc of docker containers with host's 1,17

By default, those pid are in different namespace.
Since [issue 10080](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/10080) and `--pid host`, the container pids can stay in the host's pid namespace.
There also [issue 10163: "Allow shared PID namespaces"](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10163), requesting a  `--pid=container:id`

> what all the kernel changes are happening when we create a new process inside the docker container

Note and update May 2016:  [issue 10163 and `--pid=container:id`](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10163) is now resolved by [PR 22481](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/22481) for docker 1.12, allowing to join another container's PID namespace.

---

No changes on the kernel level, only the use of:

- cgroups or control groups. A key to running applications in isolation is to have them only use the resources you want.
- union file systems to provide the building blocks for containers