# Docker pid namespace and Host

Tags: docker

When we run the same process in docker and in host system, how it differentiates one from the other, from the perspective of audit logs?

Can I view the process running in docker in host system?

Comment: How to view the process task structure in linux system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not run the *same* process (same pid) in docker and in host, since the purpose of a container is to provide **isolation** (both processes and filesystem)

I mentioned in your previous question "[Docker Namespace in kernel level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32859298/6309)" that the pid of a process run in a container could be made visible from the host.

But in term of audit log, you can [configure logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/reference/logging/overview/) in order to follow only containers, and ignore processes running directly on host.

For instance, in [this article](http://www.wolfe.id.au/2015/05/03/syslog-logging-driver-for-docker/), Mark configures `rsyslog` to isolate the Docker logs into their own file.

> To do this create `/etc/rsyslog.d/10-docker.conf` and copy the following content into the file using your favorite text editor.

```
# Docker logging
daemon.* {
 /var/log/docker.log
 stop
}
```

> In summary this will write all logs for the daemon category to `/var/log/docker.log` then stop processing that log entry so it isn’t written to the systems default syslog file.

That should be enough to clearly differentiate the host processes logs (in regular syslog) from the ones running in containers (in `/var/log/docker.log`)

Update May 2016:  [issue 10163 and `--pid=container:id`](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10163) is closed by [PR 22481](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/22481) for docker 1.12, allowing to join another container's PID namespace.

Comment: Process may be same...when i run that process in docker and in host that takes different pid.In Global audit logs i could able to see only process related with host system..How can i get the process id of docker in host as well?

Comment: @SowndaryaK if the pid are different, that should mean two different processes. You would only see a pid from a container process on the host if that container was run with the option `--pid host`, as I mentioned in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/a/32859298/6309 (also mentioned in this very answer above)

Comment: when i give --pid=host then, then i can see process which are running inside host...then how about the docker container processes?

Comment: "how about the docker container processes": that is still being discussed in issue https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10163

Comment: How the processes running container is different from host processes?

Comment: @SowndaryaK by default, they are in a different namespace, in order to be isolated from the host.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92019/discussion-between-sowndarya-k-and-vonc).

Comment: please sorry if this question is seems to be silly,i wanted to know  How the namespace of the docker will be called when we run the docker run command and how it is internally mapped to the kernel?